# Using linkify option on Django_tables2 columns to create links

Tags: django, django-tables2

I want to add a link to my listview using linkify in the [Columns of the API Reference](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#columns). I am using Django 2 with Django_tables2 v 2.0.0b3

I have a URL with two context variables `name`, which is passed from the ListView and the slug field `species`:

**URL.py**

```
app_name = 'main'

urlpatterns = [
#The list view
path('genus/<slug:name>/species/', views.SpeciesListView.as_view(), name='species_list'),
# The Detail view
path('genus/<name>/species/<slug:species>', views.SpeciesDetailView.as_view(), name='species'),
]
```

The DetailView is currently accessible if I manually type the URL.

I want to use the option where I can enter a tuple with (viewname, args/kwargs).

For the tables.py I tried:

```
class SpeciesTable(tables.Table):
    species =tables.Column(linkify=('main:species', {'name': name,'slug':species}))
```

This gave a `NameError: name 'species' is not defined`.

```
species =tables.Column(linkify=('main:species', {'name': kwargs['name'],'slug':kwargs['species']}))
```

This gave a `NameError: name 'kwargs' is not defined`.

I also tried changing the following variables to strings:

```
species =tables.Column(linkify=('main:species', {'name': 'name','slug':'species'}))
species =tables.Column(linkify=('main:species', {'name': 'name','slug':'object.species'}))
```

These attempts gave a `NoReverseMatch Reverse for 'species' with keyword arguments '{'name': 'name', 'slug': 'species'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['genus\\/(?P<name>[^/]+)\\/species\\/(?P<species>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']`

Formatting it as any of the following will give a `SyntaxError`:

```
species =tables.Column(kwargs={'main:species','name': name,'slug':species})
species =tables.Column(args={'main:species','name': name,'slug':species})
species =tables.Column(kwargs:{'main:species','name': name,'slug':species})
species =tables.Column(args:{'main:species','name': name,'slug':species})
```

How would I add a link similar to `{% url "main:species" name=name species =object.species %}`?  Currently there are no example in the docs to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Alternative option for the linkify parameter

After many tries I never got the linkify parameter option working the way I wanted. However, I did find a way to achieve the same result.

You can add a render_foo function. For instance, if you want to render an ID with a link one can add the render_id function to their table class. This function will then overwrite the existing rendering for the attribute ID.

More information about this can be found on: https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-data.html

## models.py

```
# models.py

import django_tables2 as tables
from django.urls import reverse


class Person:
   name = model.CharField(default='Jeffrey Lebowski', max_length=256)
   nick_name = model.CharField(default='the Dude', max_length=256)
   hates_hearing = model.CharField(default="Where's the money Lebowski?", max_length=256)


class PersonTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap.html"
        fields("id", "name", "nick_name", "hates_hearing", )
   
    def render_id(self, record):
        """
        This function will render over the default id column. 
        By adding <a href> HTML formatting around the id number a link will be added, 
        thus acting the same as linkify. The record stands for the entire record
        for the row from the table data.
        """
        return format_html('<a href="{}">{}</a>',
                           reverse('example-view-name',
                           kwargs={'id':, record.id}),
                           record.id)
```

For this to work one would also need to specify the view, url, and template.

## views.py

```
# views.py

from django_tables2 import SingleTableView

class ExampleTableView(SingleTableView):
    model = Person
    table_class = PersonTable
    template_name = "app_name/example.html"
    object_list = Person.objects.all()
```

## urls.py

```
# urls.py

from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:id>', views.detail, name="example-view-name"),
]
```

## example.html

```
# templates/app_name/example.html

{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>EXAMPLE HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
   <section>
       <div>
           <h1>EXAMPLE TABLE</h1>
           <p>Here one can find the result of the django-tables2 output</p>
           {% render_table table %}
       </div>
   </section>
</body>
<footer>
    <p>That's it.</p>
</footer>
</html>
```

Please note, one has to add django-tables2 to the installed apps list. Otherwise the template does not work.

Maybe this a good alternative. If someone has any comments or improvements, let me know.

Answer (score 7):

Try to think from the perspective of a row. In each row, the table needs the species of *that row*. The mechanism used in django-tables2 for that is an accessor. It enables you to tell django-tables2 the value you want it to use for a certain value. You cannot use variables (like `name` and `species` for that, because you want them to be retrieved from each record.

So using the accessor (usually abbreviated with `A`), your first example looks like this:

```
class SpeciesTable(tables.Table):
    species = tables.Column(linkify=('main:species', {'name': tables.A('name'),'slug': tables.A('species')}))
```

The concept of [Accessors](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-data.html#using-accessors) is usable in multiple places, also to change the value you want to render in a column.

I'd suggest defining [`get_absolute_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) methods on your models though. This is nice because usually when you want to show a link to the model, you have an instance of it, so in templates it's a matter of `{{ species.get_absolute_url }}`, for the `linkify` argument to django-tables2 columns, you mostly can get away with `linkify=True`.

You are right about the docs on `linkify`, they certainly need improvement.

Comment: I added some examples to the docs on `linkify`: https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2/commit/204a7f23860d178afc8f3aef50512e6bf96f8f6b

Comment: This did not work `'name': tables.A('name')` because the `name` variable was being passed as a context variable from the previous page and not included in the table.

Comment: the variable 'name' is passed by a `get_context_data` function `context["name"] = self.kwargs['name']`. The slug field is loaded from the queryset which I think you got

Comment: I think this is a use case not supported by the current implementation of the column. You can probably get this to work quickly using a [`TemplateColumn`](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#templatecolumn)

Comment: Ok thanks I was wondering what I was doing wrong. It would be cool to have a dictionary of context variables passed for the URL the current format with the accessor was not really too obvious to me

Comment: ok that worked here is the solution `species =tables.TemplateColumn('<a href="{% url "main:species" name value %}">{{value}}</a>')`