# Don't get linkify=True working within Django-Tables2 Column

Tags: django, django-tables2

I want to display two tables a single page/view (using MultiTableMixin). Within each row there should be links to the instance (display), modification and deletion. Classical access to (c)RUD operations through extra columns compared to the actual model. I also saw a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52133275/using-linkify-option-on-django-tables2-columns-to-create-links) already. But it didn't work as expected.

I wanted to simplify/ clean up my code using linkify instead of LinkColumn. Unfortunately, I already struggle with the display part. The following old style works:

```py
columns.LinkColumn(
    "matching:search",
    args=[A("pk")],
    verbose_name="",
    text="display",
    orderable=False,
)
```

As stated by the docs, using `linkify=True` should call the `get_absolute_url` method of the underlying model instance. The method clearly is present and tested. Hence, I added to the table  `display = tables.Column(orderable=False, verbose_name="", linkify=True). But all I get is "--" within the now created display column instead of the wanted link. Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2/blob/5700abfaaf75c7eef7b002644e85dd8d52f78344/django_tables2/columns/base.py#L307) I see a needed accessor attribute for the linkify to take effect. Am I understanding something wrong?

Any help to clearify would be appreciated.